# Draw graph of $y=x^2$ using these equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Draw graph of $y=x^2$ using these equations:

$x^2-4x+3=0$

$x^2-7=0$

$x^2-2x+5=0$

I don't understand how to put these equations in a form from which they are ready to be plotted on a graph. Do I solve for $y$? How do I do it?

Answer (score 4):

$\color{blue}{y} = \color{blue}{x^2}\;$

$$ \color{blue}{x^2} - 4x + 3 = 0 \tag{1}$$

$$\color{blue}{x^2} - 7 = 0\tag{2}$$

$$\color{blue}{x^2} - 2x + 5 = 0\tag{3}$$

$(1)\quad y = 4x-3$

$(2) \quad y = 7$

$(3)\quad y =2x-5$